# realtime update an objects variables from hashmap of those variables

Tags: java, variables, hashmap

This questions is probably noob rated, but I have no solution and all googleling led me to updating values in hash, and that I already know.

I am making a RPG, and this question affect everything that has stats (like equipment class that has `addedStr, addedIQ, addedAgi` and so on).

To simplify the update process, I have added all these variables in an `hashmap` and update the `hashmap` the following way:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> statsHash = new HashMap<>();

void setStatsHash() {
  statsHash.put("addedCon", addedCon);
  statsHash.put("addedStr", addedStr);
  statsHash.put("addedAgi", addedAgi);
  ...
}

void changeStatsHash(String inStat, int inChange) {
  statsHash.put("addedCon", statsHash.get("addedCon") + 1);
  (this is an example, do not point out that inStat and inChange is dummy variables)
}
```

And this works well, I can update the stats in the `hashmapv. The problem is the following:

```
myEquipment.changeStatsHash("addedCon", 1);
myEquipment.printStatsHash();
System.out.println(myEquipment.addedCon);
```

When I do this, the `printStatsHash` indicate `addedCon = whatever` it was before `+1`. 
But `myEquipment.addedCon` has not changed.

So my question is this and this only:

**How to update the "mother" variable from the `hashmap` everytime a variable in the `hashmap` changes?**

I was hoping that the `hashmap` was a `pointer` to the original object and that they would change together, but it does not seem to be that way.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show more code. Where is the "mother variable" declared?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like something you'd use the Reflection API for. Though from your example I'm not really convinced of the usefulness of the whole idea of storing variables in a map. What is this update process and how exactly does the map simplify it?

Comment: As I said, if you really need this, check out [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). It was designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: myEquipment is instance of class derived from hashmap?If u add it's code to the post it will make the question more clear

Comment: "How to update the "mother" variable from the hashmap everytime a variable in the hashmap changes?" ... Reflection should always be the solution of last resort for almost any programming problem (for a variety of reasons).  A preferred approach for this kind of problem is to use the Observer pattern.  Observable objects will "notify" any of a number of objects about changes to their state.  Moreover, JavaFX includes a Binding API which binds property values uni- or bi-directionally.  The Observer pattern will provide a more robust solution than Reflection.

Comment: If you want good suggestions, you should _share more code_. Especially the `printStatsHash` method, which you mention is not displaying what you're expecting.

Comment: The "mother variable" is primitive int/String variables in the beginning of the class. You might be right when stating that they are not objects but primitive variables. (Tried changing addedCon from int to Integer but had no effect). The reason it simplifies cannot really be read from the question, but it boils down to two reasons: 1: The number of variables change often (the engine will be used to make several games) so I need a design that interact with "all variables of X". 2: Many of my classes needs this ("player" class  with subclasses alone have like 30+ stat variables).

Comment: I gladly share "printStatsHash()", but its pointless since I have no problem with it. It prints the value in the hash perfectly. What I want is the value in the hash to update the primitive value of the Equipment .

Comment: public void printStatsHash() {
    Iterator iterator = statsHash.keySet().iterator();
  
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   String key = iterator.next().toString();
   String value = statsHash.get(key).toString();
  
   if (statsHash.get(key)>0) {System.out.println(key + " " + value);}
   
}
    System.out.println();
}

Comment: Your example code calls `myEquipment.addedCon` but you store everything ino the HashMap. When do you actually assign a value to the field `addedCon`? Do you update the value after assigning a value to it? Why don't you write a method that simply returns the value stored in the map based on the key you provide as agrumend? I'm not a big fan of your design approach though TBH. Storing everything in a single map might sound convenient but what if multiple identical items can be attached? Remember, this "engine" should server multiple games

Answer (score 0):

> How to update the "mother" variable from the hashmap everytime a variable in the hashmap changes?

The Map contains a different Object than the "mother" variable (I presume here that you mean `instance` variable), so changes to one are not reflected in the other (it is unclear if both are even Objects, or if the instance variable is a primitive).

To update a value from either location (the `Map` or `instance variable`), make both refer to the same Object. For example, you could wrap the value into it's own class:

```
public class IntWrapper{
    private int value;

    public void setValue(int val){ value = val;}
    public int getValue(){ return value;} 
    public void incrementValue(int inc){ setValue(value + inc);}
}
...

HashMap<String,IntWrapper> statsHash = new HashMap<>();
addedCon = new IntWrapper();
statsHash.put("addedCon", addedCon); 
...

void changeStatsHash(String inStat, int inChange) {
    statsHash.put("addedCon", statsHash.get("addedCon").incrementValue(1));
}
```

As along as both the instance variable `addedCon` and that within the Map are the same Object. This being said, I'm not sure I grasp how placing the value in the `Map` 'simplifies the process'.

Comment: I see how this could work, but for over 100 different variables (player variables, monster variables, equipment variables, spell variables and tons of different subclasses) I do not see how it would help either. If this is the best solution I guess I have two options: 1: Stop using hashmaps and make a class that at all times keeps track of all available stats of all class types so I can check if a given class has that stat or 2: Use only hashmaps and ignore the fact that the "mother variable values" are wrong from the first change?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a stupid solution but:

Can I simply have all interaction of variables go through the hashmap changing method in a switch? Add a detector that changes the primitive stat either to the same sum or change it with the same amount?

Like this:

```
switch(inStat)
case: "addedcon" {statsHash.put("addedCon", statsHash.get("addedCon") + inChange); addedCon = statsHash.get("addedCon"); break;
```

OR this:

```
switch(inStat)
case: "addedcon" {statsHash.put("addedCon", statsHash.get("addedCon") + inChange); addedCon = addedCon + inChange; break;
```

Is this horrible coding? Or would it work? (or both).